# What fonts are similar to Candara, but available on Google Docs?

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

I've got several documents using Candara that I'd like to shift from Microsoft Word to Google Docs for collaboration; which font is going to be the closest match when using Google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Orienta](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Orienta) is not bad.

[Galdeano](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Galdeano) has a bit of the same feel to it.

Comment: Galdeano seems the closest in feel, though it doesn't render particularly well on-screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Does it actually matter what font you use in Google Docs for collaboration? Surely if you are using a corporate font for branding purposes or whatever, it would feature on the report or website showing the results of your consultation.

You are probably going to have difficulty maintaining the style if you do have several authors all poking, adding and tweaking your content anyway.

That said, from my eye, the best offerings in Google docs for a Candara-style font would be:

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Rosario
(Not quite as detailed, and slightly narrower)

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nobile
(Much squarer, but a similar size and shape)

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Quattrocento+Sans
(Probably one of my favorite Google Fonts, similar size and weight, similar ligatures, tails, etc, just a lot simpler—which, for screen use, is good for legibility)

Comment: Thanks; Rosario has a very similar feel, but looks plain next to Candara.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look for the same for a different reason (web page) and I found two candidates:

1. [Merriweather Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Merriweather+Sans)
2. [PT sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Sans)

What I considered the most was how much open the ductus was and the italics and, of course, the proportions and this stroke modulation (less noticeable in these ones than in Candara). Have a look at the "a", for instance.

Answer (score -1):

[Actor](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Actor) is an excellent alternative.